# Code Style Sass в phpStorm 2017.2

Tags: phpstorm, sass, less

В процессе верстки сайтов использую Less и phpStorm. Хочу перейти на Sass.

Столкнулся с неудобством: phpStrom требует наличие обязательного пробела после двоеточия.

```
ul
    margin: 0
```

В настройках **Editor > Code Style > CSS** есть галка **Spaces > After colon**, для Sass же такой надстройки нет.

[image: Editor > Code Style > CSS]
[image: Editor > Code Style > Sass]

Есть ли какая-то возможность обойти этот момент? Спасибо.

Comment: `phpStrom требует наличие обязательного пробела после двоеточия` что за бред? Я наоборот удалил все ненужные пробелы, может это у `sass` такие требования?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, все просто :)

**Editor > Code Style > CSS**
ставим галку **Spaces > After colon**

Эта настройка распространяется и на Sass, в результате пробел после двоеточия ставится автоматически.

P.S. По-умолчанию она скорее всего включена.